# IF Bitmap was found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bitmap, getpixel

I'm trying to detect with the bitmap if it's my first turn or second turn (since it's a coin toss and it shows red or blue), but I'm having trouble making an IF argument. I tryed some things and none seemed to work...

```
        private void fastlevel_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fastlevel.Checked)
        {   
            //Click X;Y
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            //MessageBox.Show("OK");

            {
                //if  bitmap was found
                MessageBox.Show("FIRST TURN");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SECOND TURN");
        }
    }
```

I'm also having trouble with it finding the bitmap I know the files is in resources and I see what I want it to find but It doesn't

Comment: at the moment it just takes the screenshot and searches for the bitmap, it also clicks in certain cords to start the game.

Comment: I don't know how to make it compare to the if the bitmap was found, so if it was found it does "x"

Comment: I don't see any code in there that is even remotely related to bitmaps...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you intend to do, but normally you can add a variable to keep track of the state of your function. If you need more states, you can use a switch statement as well.

```
 private void fastlevel_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    int turn=0;
        if (fastlevel.Checked)
        {   
            //Click X;Y
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            //MessageBox.Show("OK");
            if(turn==0)
            {
                turn++;
                //if  bitmap was found
                MessageBox.Show("FIRST TURN");
            {
            else
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("SECOND TURN");
                turn++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: "turn" will always be zero where you have it scoped.